# Matlab GUI, sometimes listbox disappears. I used: set(handles.listbox,'value',1) and seems it does not work

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listbox

In the GUI, I have two listboxes, and the data in these two listboxes can be passed to each other. A user can pass all the data to the other one, he can also select some data and pass to the other one.

The problem is: Sometime, the listbox will disappear, but all the pushbuttons works as expected. And Matlab gives a warning: Warning: multi-selection listbox control
requires that Value be an integer within String range.Control will not be rendered until all of its parameter values are valid.

I did  some research, someone advises to use this: set(handles.listbox,'value',1) . But it does not solve this problem.

And what's more, I cannot figure out under what kind of circumstance this error may happen. 
Can you guys please tell me how to solve this? And in which case this error may happen?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to dump out `get(handles.listbox,'value')` it callbacks to see what the offending value is.  Also `'String'`, and my guess is the cell array is shorter than the integer in `value`.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! I will try! after so long time, only you answered me, I appreciate it! When you say  'the cell array is shorter than the integer in value'.you mean the rows of cell array?